# jQuery is undefined at pages located in another folder

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working in a website which includes master page and content pages. In the master page I added these jQuery lines:

```
$(function () {
        $('.ticker').easyTicker({
            direction: 'down',
            visible: 1,
            interval: 3500
        });
    });
```

Which displays a movement of the banner in all website pages. This jQuery is working fine, unless the content page is located under another folder. i.e. master page is located at the main project folder, and I created another folder called "matches" and created under that a content page. This page popup an error says `SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined`.

I added all scripts needed and imported scripts path in head section. I tried to put jQuery in content pages and tried to import scripts path on each content pages and tried to change `$` to `jQuery` but I'm getting the same error.

This is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: does ur content pages contain any scripts..?

Comment: @Outlooker no its empty page, only the master page contains jQuery scripts.

Comment: may be some refrence to js page will be wrong. Just check it again.

Comment: @maddy the scripts are working fine in the pages located on the same master page folder. If the content page is under another folder then it doesn't work.

Comment: could u show a screenshot of ur console errors...??

Comment: once u comment the easy ticker function,could u check if there any any console errors..?

Comment: Tried full path to folder , file ? Can describe "master page and content pages." ?

Comment: Have you looked into the FireBug if your Script files are being loaded or not ??

Comment: @Outlooker I didn't understant, I just run that page and pressed yes when the browser asked me to debug the page.

Comment: @guest271314 what do you mean by tried tried full path to folder?

Comment: @Puneet the script is working fine in all other pages, only this page its not working just because its inside a folder.

Comment: "http:" or "https:" "//" "full.path/to/Scripts/**folder**/abc.js"

Comment: @guest271314 yes I wrote the full path but getting the same error.

Comment: Tried including `js` text from file within `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tag on `html` page ? Can create stacksnippets http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/ , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 the problem is not in the script because its working fine. The problem is in the folder, is there constrictions on the scripts where it work only with the same folder's pages?

Comment: "the problem is not in the script because its working fine. The problem is in the folder, is there constrictions on the scripts where it work only with the same folder's pages?" Not certain ? Are all `<script>` tags at image at OP included in other pages ?, can create http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 I am using an external controls which includes scripts as well, I can't include js regarding to that.